# Rails 4 InvalidCrossOriginRequest error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, security

Started getting loads of these errors today:

```
F, [2018-08-03T18:02:08.783602 #22987] FATAL -- :
ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest (Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-
origin JavaScript embedding.):
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:225:in `verify_same_origin_request'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:239:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
....
```

I never saw this before. The only thing that changed in my application today: I set up a controller behind a generic route to catch routing errors that kept popping up in the prod log due to tons of lame script kiddies probing my sites, it was so annoying that I now just block every IP behind a routing error no questions asked.

I wouldn't care much about this but sometimes some very specific morons try to scrape my sites stealing my stuff so I'm mainly concerned about them coming up with something new, which would also mean I've slightly underestimated the size of their brains.

And now I am getting this error but I have no idea who tries to load what, where from, nothing relevant in the web server logs; how can I figure out what's going on?

Comment: Is this happening on every controller or only on a specific controller?

Comment: I have no clue if it is happening on a controller or type of request or any hint at all, there is no relevant info in the logs and also the timestamp on the entry does not correlate to anything in the web server logs.

Comment: Well one of your pages is probably loading an external JS library in a `<script>` tag. Do you know which webpage this happens in?

Comment: It actually says a script on another site (domain) is trying to load from mine. Am I missing something?

Comment: one of your controller is getting targeted by some external website. Cross-Origin allows your controller to be only called via the origin (which is set to be your domain)

Comment: Ok but how do I figure out who calls what? that's what I want to know. Nothing else shows in the logs.